# Inserting one week (seven sparate days) and some other data into database using a for loop and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

This is my data:

```
Day            From:     To:

Sunday         12PM      8PM

Monday         12PM      9PM

Tuesday        12PM      6PM

Wednesday      12PM      6PM

Thursday       12PM      6PM

Friday         12PM      5PM

Saturday       12PM      5PM
```

How do I go about using a for loop to insert the above data (from $_POST) into my MySQL database with PHP'S PDO?  My input fields are named SundayTimeFrom, SundayTimeTo, MondayTimeFrom, MondayTimeTo, etc.

Pseudocode that I threw together really fast:

```
$sql = 'Insert INTO tableName (day, from, to) Values (:day, :from, :to)';
for(i = Sunday; I < Saturday; i++) //what do I do here?
{
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":day", $i, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":from", $_POST[$i + 'TimeFrom'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":to", $_POST[$i + 'TimeTo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop 7 times and use date('l',time()+24hours in secs) to get your days in letters.

Look at date('l') here http://php.net/date

But the best would be to change your $_POST to get something like `$_POST['days'][0][from] = '10PM';` and `$_POST['days'][0][to] = '8PM';`

You can do this by writing : `<input type="text" name="days[][from]" value="10PM" />` if i remember correct

or simply `<input type="text" name="days[Monday][from]" value="10PM" />` and `<input type="text" name="days[Monday][to]" value="8PM" />` and doing a `foreach($_POST['days'] as $value)`

As you can see you have a lot of solutions :)

Comment: Oh okay. So I turn it into an array where days[] would be days[0] (aka Sunday) to days[6] (aka Saturday) correct?

Comment: Yep you can do that. I don't know how you display your form on the html side so i can't help ou that much.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of `SundayTimeFrom` and `SundayTimeTo` the fields would have the names `schedule[sunday][from]` and `schedule[sunday][to]` you could use a foreach loop like

```
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":day", $day);
$stmt->bindParam(":from", $from);
$stmt->bindParam(":to", $to);

foreach( $_POST['schedule'] as $day=>$span ) {
  someDataValidationHere($day, $span);
  $from = $span['from'];
  $to = $span['to'];
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

(untested)

Answer (score 0):

Say your array is

```
$schedule = array (sunday => array (from=>"12PM", to=> "8PM"),
                   monday => array (from=>"1PM", to=> "9PM"),
                    tuesday => array (from=>"2PM", to=> "10PM"),
                    wednesday => array (from=>"3PM", to=> "11PM"),
  );
```

use _REQUEST["schedule"] and save in some array say $schedule.

now use foreach to save the array in the database.

```
  foreach ($schedule as $day=>$temp1) {
    foreach ($temp1 as $key=>$time) {
      if($key == "from")
        $from = $time;
      else if($key == "to")
        $to = $time;
    }
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("Insert INTO tableName (day, from, to) Values (:day, :from, :to)");
    $sth->execute(array(':day'=> $day, ':from'=> $from, ':to'=> $to));
  }
```